# JTextField Limit user input to a certain length

Tags: java

I have a JTextField where I want the following validations.

User shouldn't be allowed to enter more than 5 characters, on typing 6th character it should prompt the user about exceeding length and prevent user from typing further.

Irrespective of whether user types in upper case or lower case, the text field should display the text in upper case only.

Integers are not allowed to be input by the text field.

How do I go about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: any try that is not working and you want to share with us???

Comment: One option you could look into would be a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ: I find Ingila Ejaz's question legitimate, but yours not! There is no need for such a comment!